# How to have different values for a set of columns in a row (no duplicates in a row) in JPA

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa

I have a model

```
@Entity
@Table(name="meetings")
public class Meeting {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="meeting_id")
    private int meetingId;

    @Column(name="meeting_date")
    private Date meetingDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="mem1")
    private Member mem1;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="mem2")
    private Member mem2;
}
```

In this, I do not want to allow mem1 and mem2 to be the same. Is there any constraint I can add in my JPA or even native SQL to ensure this? Note - I can have 2 rows with same values of mem1 and mem2. But in a row, mem1 and mem2 must be different.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_constraint

Comment: @JBNizet so, @Check(constraints="mem1<>mem2 AND mem2<>mem3 and mem3<>mem1") would work? (If there were 3 members)

Comment: Test it, and you'll know.

Comment: @JBNizet yup works.. Thanks

Comment: Just a small suggestion: it's almost 2018. Don't code in the database. Validate your data *before* it hits the db, this will reduce contention. Use declarative validation (see e.g. here:  http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/), it integrates smoothly with JPA by firing automatically before persisting and updating entities. Your constraint is dead easy to validate using `@ScriptAssert`, if you don't like it, I'm sure there are plenty of custom constraint libraries to use.